# Search for either of two words using isearch

Tags: isearch, pdf-tools

Is there a way to use isearch (only search i think that works in pdf-tools)? to search for either of two words at the same time? It would search in the pdf for 'eval' *or* 'valid' and move forward in each occurrence of either word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C-M-s to invoke `isearch-forward-regexp` then type `aaa\|bbb`, where aaa is your first word and bbb is your second.

Alternatives, just C-s to invoke `isearch`, then press M-r to toggle to regex.

Comment: right Drew. thx. forgot about that.